# How do you open a jsx component in a different window on a button click?

Tags: reactjs

On a button click a new window should be opened and on that window I'm trying to display a separate JSX component. Kinda like flipping to the next page on a book. I have searched for hours only finding antiquated answer's. **I just need some guidance any help is appreciated**. Below is the code:

```
onClick() {
window.open()
    }
```

EDIT: I am working in visual studio code and testing my create-react-app on port 3000.

EDIT: My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47574490/10565406)

Comment: If the JSX in the new tab is in a separate React app at a different url... sure. Otherwise, your question does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Ok i'll rephrase it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a component in new window on a click in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574490/open-a-component-in-new-window-on-a-click-in-react)

Comment: I tried these methods and none worked

Comment: Did you tried the npm package that is specifically for this case? Check this out if you haven't: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-new-window

Comment: Yes but you can't assign the window on a button click that was my main issues with importing that npm